# Is setAccessToken necessary after refreshToken? - Google API PHP

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

Here is my code:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("dayPlanner");
$client->setClientId(env('googleClientID'));
$client->setClientSecret(env('googleClientSecret'));
$client->setAccessToken(session('token'));

if($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->refreshToken($user->refreshToken);
    $token = $client->getAccessToken();
    session(['token' => $token]);
    $client->setAccessToken($token); // necessary..?
}
```

This works, but I don't fully understand it. Most examples online show the refreshToken (and getAccessToken for the session data), but none I've seen then use setAccessToken again. Logic dictates this is necessary, and it works, but I'd like a definitive answer and to understand this a little better.

(Note, Laravel syntax used for setting/retriving session data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the PHP API code should answer your question.. See [the code](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Client.php)

If you look at the getAccessToken code, it just returns "token" that was already there. 
 public function getAccessToken()
  {
    return $this->token;
  }
So doing a setAccessToken to set a token that was received using getAccessToken doesn't make much sense.
During the refreshToken setting time (see the code), it'll update the accessToken if there is none.